# Does Apache Olingo support Oracle database

Tags: oracle, odata, olingo

I want to expose Oracle database data with an Odata endpoint.I tried using JayData server on node.js but it currently supports only mongo db but not oracle.So before I start trying connecting Oracle with Apache Olingo I would like to know if someone has already been this path.Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully used Oracle with Olingo from java JPA and EclipseLink

Comment: Thanks Chaim. I was also able to do it by following the instructions in link-http://scn.sap.com/community/gateway/blog/2014/02/05/odata-producer-using-apache-olingo-with-mysql-jpa-tomcat-web-server.It worked for Oracle as well.I have imported some corrupted JARs which created some issue.After replacing correct JARs I was successfully able to setup OData endpoint

Comment: For some reason your link doesn't seem to bve working. I believe you meant this: http://scn.sap.com/community/gateway/blog/2014/02/05/odata-producer-using-apache-olingo-with-mysql-jpa-tomcat-web-server